# Safest way of using global variables in python: module or "global" keyword?

Tags: python, global-variables

I have to share around 10 variables between functions, which are contained in the same .py file. The variables will be modified in almost every function. I know that global variables are evil,  but unfortunately for now I have to keep few of them as global, while the rest I have been able to change the implementation and to pass them as an argument.

One way of doing this would be using the "global" keyword, but I have run into another option, that would be placing them in an empty module, and importing the module every time.

I am just a beginner in python, what would be the best way to do this?

EDIT: This is a rewriting of a code based almost completely on global variables. Almost all the functions are now in a class, the variables are used with self.name_var. However, since we are using multiprocess with Array, few variables have to remain globals.

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: global variables are not evil if you use them wisely.

Answer (score 0):

Just do not do it, put all the functions, if they are related, in a class and make the variables accessible with self. Using a different module is worst.